# Lua with table.sort

Tags: lua

```
local t = {{15,6},{11,8},{13,10}}
```

I need to show the table in order on the second number

exemple:

1 -> {13,10} -- why 10 > 8

2 -> {11,8} -- why 8 > 6

3 -> {15,6}

Comment: You need to set up comparator properly

Comment: -1: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We generally like it when people make some effort to solve the problem on their own before asking. In your case, all you needed to do was look up `table.sort` in the Lua documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`table.sort`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) takes a function that is used to compare the two (it uses `<` if one isn't provided). So simply pass a function that will be called to do the comparison on the elements.

```
local t = {{15,6},{11,8},{13,10}}

table.sort(t, function(lhs, rhs) return lhs[2] < rhs[2] end)
```